# rewrite a query to have pagination

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have a program, where the user provides an sql query that can be executed on a database (the details of the database to run on are also provided by the user). This query is executed on the database and the results processed at a later point.

A new feature requires that the query is executed in a paged fashion i.e. if the user's query would return 20 records normally, and the user had provided a page size of 5, then the query should execute 4 times and retrieve 5 records each time.

I am able to do this for a select query without CTEs, but I am not certain how to handle a general query, which has CTEs in it.

I modify the query for CTEs as shown below:

```
public static String rewrite(String sql) {
    return "select * from ("
            + "select (row_number() over ()) as generated_row_number, t.* "
            + "from ("
            + sql
            + ") as t"
            + ") "
            + "where generated_row_number < ?"
            + " and generated_row_number >= ?"; 
}
```

Where the start index and page size are added later as parameters.

How would I handle similar functionality for a query containing a CTE?

The database can be assumed to be DB2, although a generic solution would be preferred.

The user connecting to the database also does not have privileges to create views.

Comment: How about using offset? "order by 1 offset 10((page number - 1) * pagesize) ROWS fetch NEXT 5(your page size) ROWS ONLY"

Answer (score 0):

A handy way to query in SQL is by using offset-fetch. I use this often for pagination.

```
Select StockCode,Description,Quantity from Inventory order by StockCode offset 0 ROWS fetch NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

So in code it would be something like

```
public static string(int Page, int PerPage)
{
    return "Select StockCode,Description,Quantity from Inventory order by StockCode offset " + ((Page - 1) * PerPage).ToString() + " ROWS fetch NEXT " + PerPage.ToString() + " ROWS ONLY"
}
```

If you need a more generic solution you could try a nested select:

```
public static String rewrite(String sql, int Page, int PerPage)
{
    return "Select * from (" + sql + ") order by 1 offset " + ((Page - 1) * PerPage).ToString() + " ROWS fetch NEXT " + PerPage.ToString() + " ROWS ONLY"
}
```

Comment: I get the following error, using this : `select * from test
offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only`

`An unexpected token "from test" was found following "select * ".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.127
`

Comment: You need to have "order by"

Comment: Still does not work : `select * from test
order by 1
offset 20 rows
fetch next 20 rows only

An unexpected token "offset 20 rows 
fetch next 20 rows only" was found following "m test 
order by 1 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.13.127`

Comment: What version of sql are you running?

Comment: The server is DB2 express c 10.5, in this case.

Comment: Mmm, in that case you will need to set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS and then use LIMIT-OFFSET: SELECT StockCode,Description FROM Inventory ORDER BY StockCode LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10

Comment: Unfortunately not an option, as the database is up to the user :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static String rewrite(String sql) 
{
    return   "with tmptable as (" + sql + ")"
            + " select * from ("
            + " select row_number() over () as generated_row_number, t.* "
            + " from tmptable t
            + ") tmp"
            + " where tmp.generated_row_number < ?"
            + " and tmp.generated_row_number >= ?"; 
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the original query also contains a WITH clause, which is what I was having trouble with. It also does not work for some simple selects, failing with error -153